# Loading configs from an external file in React / Babel / Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, config, babeljs

I have defined a config module that merges `defaultConfig` which I've defined within the module, along with loaded configs `config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), argv.config)))`.  So basically I merge my configs like so `config = defaultsDeep(config, defaultConfig)` then export `exports = module.exports = config`.

The question that I have is, how can I access configurations at the component level?  I'm using React / Webpack / Babel.  What I'm experiencing at the moment is that even though in my test environment I pass the config file as an arg `"nodejs\node.exe" server --config ../conf/sqrweb.config.json`, when I define configs intended for React components those aren't overriding the default configs, instead what's defined in the `defaultConfig` are being loaded.

What am I missing here?!

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is run in Node.js, so you can read system variable in its config file. And there is definitely a way to pass that value to bundle file

Not sure what you exactly want. But if you want to pass a variable from webpack config file to React component, look this https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/386